# Would using an oscillating LED light save power?

Tags: android, performance

Would my app save battery if instead of just turning on the led light I made it flash really fast like shown below or just kept it on.

```
pon.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
poff.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

while(lightShouldBeOn) {
        try{
                cam.setParameters(pon);
                Thread.sleep(delay);
                cam.setParameters(poff);
                Thread.sleep(delayoff);
        }
}
```

Comment: Surely the power consumption of an LED is much less than the power consumption of a spinning thread! That having been said, the best way to find out is to just try it. Run from a full charge down to some defined percentage using both techniques, and see which takes longer.

Comment: @Simon: That `Thread.sleep` ought to be power efficient.

Comment: @BenVoigt, but if it's for a torch app, the sleep time must be very short - I'd expect that it'll spend more time in `setParameters` than in `sleep`...

Comment: User-level Android apps aren't real-time so good luck with the fast timing necessary for realistic PWM. Premature optimization at the HW level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulse wave modulation is a well-known technique for power control of LEDs, among other devices.  As an additional benefit, the power and intensity are highly linear with duty cycle.

Normally there'll be a PWM peripheral in the processor that handles the rapid switching for you, but that would need driver support; it won't be accessible to user applications.  Here's a question which uses the driver to do it: [Set brightness of flash in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851897/set-brightness-of-flash-in-android)

But this isn't really a software question.